# RNRF - Can't redirect after upgraded to lastest

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I just upgraded my RNRF to 4.0.5, I didn't change my code from before, but the Actions won't triggered in `ComponentDidMount`. I want to make redirect if user login then it will be redirect to home, but the simple way in `ComponentDidMount` doesn't work.

```
ComponentDidMount() {
  console.log('mounted') // triggered
  Actions.Home() // didn't triggered
  console.log('test') //triggered
}
```

Comment: Hi did you find the solution for this.? Facing the same issue

Comment: I found the solution, the solution is using `setTimeout` to triggered that.